# Is there a command to rename a music file with its meta data?

Tags: command-line, rename, metadata

I’m a DJ and I’m renaming 5000 music files for future gigs. I’m looking for a way to rename these files in the format:

```
[artist/artists name] - [track title].[file extension]
```

*all lowercase*

Is there a way to use the meta data to rename the file names by any chance?

Comment: Check out mp3tag. Excellent program.

Comment: https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

[Exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is very good with regards to renaming files based upon their metadata.  As long as the metadata was properly filled out, your command would be something like:
`exiftool "-Filename<[$Artist] - [$Title].%le" -api "Filter=$_=lc" DIR`

Replace DIR with the directories (one or more) that you wish to process.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.  If this command is run under Unix/Mac, reverse any double/single quotes to avoid bash interpretation.

To make sure that this command does what you want, replace `Filename` with `Testname` to see the results without actually renaming any files.

Breakdown:
`-Filename<` Indicates that the filename is going to be changed.  The less than sign indicates that the value of the new filename is going to be copied from tags internal to the file.
`[$Artist] - [$Title]` The format for the file name using the `Artist` and `Title` tags.  These can be either ID3v1 or ID3v2_3, possibly others, according to my tests.
`.%le` - `%e` by itself is a exiftool special variable for the file extension. Placing the `l` in front of the `e` forces it to be lower case.
`-api "Filter=$_=lc"` - This filters all outputted tags by the perl expression after `Filter=`.  In this case, it will lower case the `Artist` and `Title` tags.

Comment: The correct exiftool command seems to be (exiftool 10.80 on Ubuntu 18.04):
exiftool '-Filename<${Artist;} - ${Title;}.%le' -api "Filter=$_=lc" filename1 filename2 # use -r to recurse into directories

Not sure if the version of exiftool you're using is different

Comment: I had assumed that the OP had wanted brackets surrounding the `Artist` and `Title`, though I could have been wrong.  But you are correct in adding the braces and semicolons, as that will remove any illegal characters from the filename.  For example, `AC/DC` would lose the slash.